# How can i disable the checkbox in datagrid in MUi when clicking a submit button

Tags: checkbox, material-ui, datagrid

Here is what i want to achieve that i select a multiple checkbox and grab the data from them, then click a submit button to send those data to backend, then disable those selected checkbox.
here is the code example ,which is exactly the same like mine

https://codesandbox.io/s/controlledselectiongrid-demo-mui-x-forked-3bx8gp?file=/demo.tsx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `isRowSelectable` prop to indicate if a row can be selected

material ui v5 example

```
<div style={{ height: 400, width: '100%' }}>
  <DataGrid
    {...data}
    isRowSelectable={(params: GridRowParams) => params.row.quantity > 50000}
    checkboxSelection
  />
</div>
```

you need use hook to save selected checkbox and remove them in all data you get in  `isRowSelectable`

you can save selected checkbox  in `onSelectionModelChange` prop like

```
onSelectionModelChange={(newSelectionModel) => {
                    props.setRowMultiSelect(newSelectionModel);
                    
                }}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, i successfully solved it by this method
On the hand, just on top of the above question, when i selected, and click a button, then the total row is disabled, 
but the "checked" symbol is also gone,  the symbol looks like this √  since the row is disable,

just want to ask how can i leave the "tick"symbol for user to know that the row is disable more obvious, 
i think the way to do it is to override it, but i stuck ,, wish to seek your help again , many thanks

Comment: hi I think you made a mistake in the code I need to see your code to help you, with the top solution you disable the checkbox and the whole row is not disabled just the checkbox will be disabled and it's not gone

Comment: To clarify that it is disabled after applying your solution,  what i mean is just the box which has not a tick symbol,  the whole row is totally disabled. 
lately, i've been told that no need to disable the checkbox with a tick, and you solution just already solved my problem.
Example : From Mui Docs
```
<Checkbox {...label} defaultChecked />
<Checkbox {...label} />
<Checkbox {...label} disabled />.         <=======the box is like this 
<Checkbox {...label} disabled checked /> <=====what i previously want is this
```

Comment: I told you before, to send your code in the sandbox so I can help you more